# Dynamic search filter with add and remove functionality

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal, search, solr

i was wondering if there is a frame work or some sample code to create dynamic filters for search result to allow users build results. 
i want to show user the filter they have choosen and have a small x button for them to remove the filter
like the one this site
http://www.soap.com/buy/Type=Acne+Treatments%7CBar+Soaps?s=Olay

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with JavaScript, HTML and AJAX, take a look at the [ajax-solr project](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr). The [Reuters demo site](http://evolvingweb.github.com/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.html) for ajax-solr implements this type of search filter behavior and they also walk you through how to build this with [Step 5 of their tutorial](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial%3a-step-5).

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Solr facet queries. This page should help get you started: http://searchhub.org/2009/09/02/faceted-search-with-solr/